# Update liquibase data to uppercase

Tags: sql, liquibase, servletcontextlistener

I have a table in liquibase. I want to retrieve "name" field for a particular "type" from that table and then convert name to upper case. How can I use `changeset` or `ServletContextListener` to do the same?

For example: 
My table structure is table1{ id, name, type} and i retrieve names associated to a given type. Now I want to convert these names (can be more than one) to upper case before my data is actually populated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an ETL task than a schema task. You could use Liquibase for it, but it would probably require custom code. If it is just a small set of things you might be able to do it using custom SQL.